# Why is the value group of a $C$-minimal field $O$-minimal?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Why is the value group of a $C$-minimal field  $O$-minimal and stably embedded in that field?

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please give a reference for where you found this claim. Questions given with no context are usually not well-received. The question would also be improved if you reminded people of the definitions, especially of $C$-minimal and stably embedded.

Comment: This is true for algebraically closed valued fields,and algebraically closed valued fields are exatly the $C$ -minimal fields, so I wanted to know if there is a proof without using QE?